Vscode autoformatter does not properly align the table rows in latex
I'm using vscode to write latex which I find very useful. Auto formatting has been a blessing for organizing tables, however I cannot figure out why it does not properly position the rows in their own line but keeps adding newlines after "&" and "\ \hline". The table I'm trying to format looks like this:
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|l|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Device}                                                 &
        \textbf{End-effector}                                           &
        \textbf{Actuation Technology}                                   &
        \textbf{Stimuli Type}                                           &
        \textbf{Weight (g)}                                             &
        \textbf{Wired/Wireless}                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline

        Polygerinos et al.\cite{Polygerinos_Soft_Robotics_2015}         & 1 hydraulic actuator per finger, 5 fingers & 5 soft fiber-reinforced actuators    & Kinesthetic & 285       &
        --                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline Leonardis et al.\cite{Leonardis_EMG_2015} & 1 contact point per finger phalanx, 5 fingers & 2 DC motors & Kinesthetic & 950 & -- \\ \hline Pabon
        et al.\cite{Pabon_vibro_tactile_glove_2007}                     & 3 motors per finger, 5 fingers             & Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM) motors & vibration   & undefined & -- \\ \hline
        Sanfilippo et al.\cite{Sanfilippo_haptoAudio_remote_touch_2015} & 1 motor per finger pad, 5 fingers          & Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM) motors & vibration   &
        undefined                                                       & --                                                                                                               \\ \hline Foottit et al.\cite{foottit_wearable_haptic_game_interface_2016} & 1 motor per finger pad, 5 fingers & Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM)
        motors                                                          & vibration                                  & undefined                            & --                           \\ \hline Roumeliotis et al.\cite{Roumeliotis_glove_2023} & 7 servo motors, 1 Eccentric Rotating Mass (ERM) motor per
        finger, 5 fingers                                               & Servo and vibration Motors                 & Kinesthetic feedback                 & 190         & Wired          \\ \hline Hosseini et al.\cite{Hosseini_ExoTen_Glove_2018} & TSA modules, 5
        fingers                                                         & DC motors                                  & TSA system                           & 360         & --             \\ \hline Haptx G1.\cite{haptx_glove_g1} & Matrix of tactile actuators per finger, 5 fingers & Pneumatic Actuators
                                                                        & Kinesthetic feedback                       & 450                                  & Wired                        \\ \hline HaptGlove\cite{Ozioko_HaptGlove_2022} & PneuIndenter per finger, 5 fingers & Pneumatic Actuators         & Kinesthetic
        and Cutaneous Feedback                                          & 283                                        & Wireless                                                            \\ \hline Our implementation & 2 nitinol springs per finger, 5 fingers & Nitinol Shape Memory Alloy (SMA) & Force
        Feedback                                                        & 100(Wired), 200(Wireless)                  & Wireless                                                            \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Wearable Haptic Device for the whole hand\cite{Pacchierotti_review_2017}}
\end{table*}

How can I fix this issue? I'm using latex and latex workshop formatters.
Thank you very much for your time.
